# Using identical code, Why does MVS 2019 compile this code but the Codewars compiler has some errors?

Tags: c#

**Task from codewars:**

> Write an algorithm that will identify valid IPv4 addresses in
>   dot-decimal format. IPs should be considered valid if they consist of
>   four octets, with values between 0 and 255, inclusive.
>
> Input to the function is guaranteed to be a single string.
>
> Examples Valid inputs:
>
> 1.2.3.4
>   123.45.67.89
>
> Invalid inputs:
>
> 1.2.3
>   1.2.3.4.5
>   123.456.78.90
>   123.045.067.089 Note that leading zeros (e.g. 01.02.03.04) are considered invalid.

**My solution:**

```cs
class Kata
{
    public static bool is_valid_IP(string ipAddres)
    {
        int ipnumber = 0;

        bool numberChecker(List<char> number)
        {
            string checkNum = null;
            foreach (char symb in number)
            {
                checkNum += symb.ToString();
            }
            try
            {
                byte result = Convert.ToByte(checkNum);
                if (result.ToString() == (checkNum).ToString())
                {
                    ipnumber++;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        bool getOut = false;
        ipAddres = ipAddres + '.';
        char[] ipArray = ipAddres.ToCharArray();
        List<char> check = new List<char>();
        foreach (char symbol in ipArray)
        {
            if (check.Contains('.'))
                break;
            if (symbol == '.')
            {
                getOut = numberChecker(check);
                check.Clear();
            }
            else
                check.Add(symbol);
        }
        if (getOut == true && ipnumber == 4)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
code.cs(9,31): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `,', `;', or `='
code.cs(38,22): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(38,33): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `+' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(43,19): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `foreach' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(43,35): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `in' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(43,44): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `)' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(44,13): error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed
code.cs(58,14): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `if' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(58,25): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `==' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(58,45): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `==' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(59,13): error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed
code.cs(59,13): error CS8041: Primary constructor already has a body
code.cs(62,16): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `else' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
code.cs(68,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `}'
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add what errors do you receive from _CodeWars_ compiler

Comment: It seems that Codewars compiler doesn't understand [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)

Comment: @Steve looks like that =/

Comment: https://github.com/Codewars/codewars.com/issues/1353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems CW doesn't use a compiler compatible with C# 7 or later.

You are local functions, and those are available from C# 7. You should use class-level methods instead.